# How to align multiple lines in tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, alignment

I am using the following code from this [repo](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV)

```
% Define an environment for cvskill
\newenvironment{cvskills}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} R{3cm}  L{\textwidth - 3cm}}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
}
% Define a line of cv information(skill)
% Usage: \cvskill{<type>}{<skillset>}
\newcommand*{\cvskill}[2]{%
  \skilltypestyle{#1} & \skillsetstyle{#2} \\
}
```

The issue is that when the argument # 2 of tabular exceeds one line, the argument # 1 gets vertically centered between the two lines

How can I make arg#1 vertically aligned to line#1 of arg#2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting on line 424 of `awesome-cv.cls`, one finds the following definitions:

```
% Use to align an element of tabular table
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
```

Basically, the column types `L` and `R` employed in the `cvskills` environment build on the `m` column type, which performs vertical centering. In contrast, you want vertical top-aligning.

I suggest you proceed as follows.

- First, define 3 new column types in the preamble analogously to `L`, `C`, and `R`, but with top- rather than center-aligning:

  ```
  \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
  \newcolumntype{N}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
  \newcolumntype{O}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
  ```
- Second, I think there's a slight error in the definition of the `cvskills` environment, which causes the width of the `\tabular*` environment to exceed `\textwidth`. I believe it's more correct to define it via

  ```
  \newenvironment{cvskills}{%
    \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
    \vspace{-2.0mm}
    \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % not '1ex'
    % \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt} % 0pt is the default
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} O{3cm} M{\textwidth-3.3cm}} 
  }{%
    \end{tabular*}
    \end{center}
  }
  ```

  This will leave 3mm of whitespace between the columns.

---